# i'm trying to find the first 10 bigger files at my home directory and all of my subdirectories

Tags: shell, unix

```
du -Sh|sort -rn|head
```

output :

```
    du: cannot read directory './.cache/doc': Permission denied
    du: cannot read directory './.cache/dconf': Permission denied
    du: cannot read directory './.dbus': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
find ~ -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -10
```